# What are these insects on my iris and is it bad?

Tags: identification, pests, irises

I have many plants in pots at my windows, and only my irises are affected (I have other parasites on other plants, but I usually don't really care as long as the plants are OK, as I am for bio-diversity, I let wild things like grass develop too).

They don't seem to be moving, but it's spreading on the plant. There is no sign of the leaves being eaten and the plants seem to be allright, but it's spreading quite fast and I fear the iris would suffer if it covers all the plant).

What is it? Should I get rid of it and if yes, how?

If needed, I live in France.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a heavy infestation of Iris aphids, and you will need to treat to get rid of them. You can wipe them off with a damp cloth and dispose of them, spray with neem oil or similar, or use an insecticide spray. All these methods will not resolve the issue permanently, they will only remove what's on the plant currently, unless you use a systemic insecticide, which isn't particularly recommended indoors. This means you should check them daily and crush/wipe off or spray any that you see. Info on Iris aphid here https://influentialpoints.com/Gallery/Aphis_newtoni_iris_aphid.htm

Comment: Thanks, the pot is outdoors (outwindows? :P) but I'm not found of insecticide.. will it damage the plant if I let them, or prevent them to bloom next year?

Comment: they will eventually damage the flowers if left alone and blooms this year will be ruined  - best not to use insecticide anyway, Irises often don't respond well to it - try neem or physical methods of removal instead.